# Testing notifications with unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, notifications

I have a bunch of notification types with conditions which I want to test automatically. My problem is now that I know that it is impossible to generate the notification and to check if the generated UI in the notification center looks like expected.

Because of that I tried to break it down to calling my `BroadcastReceiver` and intercept that point where I fire the notification. So at that point I can check if the notification contains all settings I expect. I have to hope that it will been rendered as expected :-)

In my `build.gradle` I added this block:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Here starts my trouble I create the `Intent` and call the receiver:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NotificationTest {
    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        NotificationManager manager = new NotificationManager();
        manager.onReceive(mMockContext, new Intent(NotificationManager.MY_ACTION));
    }
}
```

This code crashes with a `NullPointerException` because I have this nice line in my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
switch(intent.getAction()) {
```

I can imagine what happens here. The mocking API does not create a real `Intent` and my data are gone. How can I test now my notification implementation? I guess that the `PendingIntent`s which I want to test next won't work ether.

**What can I do now?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is for now to mock the intent as follow:

```
Intent action = spy(new Intent(NotificationManager.MY_ACTION));
doReturn(NotificationManager.MY_ACTION).when(action).getAction();
```

However this is just a workaround. Later I run into the issue that the `Notification.Builder()` class returns just nulls in the builder pattern so this won't fix it at all.

Comment: Mock the notification builder and spy on it as well, and verify that you set the correct values instead of looking at the returned Notification object. verify(notifBuilder).setContentTitle("aaa");